# Reverse pandas string / reverse extract pandas DF

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, extract, reverse

Good day,

I got files with path in column thus:

```
pd.DataFrame({'path':[
'C:/some_1_path/file_1.zip',
'C:/some_1_path/file_2.zip']
```

I wish to extract the pattern _\d from this like this:

```
'C:/some_1_path/file_1.zip'| '_1' 
'C:/some_1_path/file_2.zip'| '_2'
```

Since the _1 happens to be in path .str.extract() picks that one. extractall will work , but requires extra steps.

How would one do .str.extract(pattern) in reverse order? I could reverse the string but extra steps and all that.

Comment: `df.path.str.extract(r'(_\d+)(.zip)')[0]`.  This will split into 2 with `.zip` as an additional column, and then return the first column only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a negative lookahead to ensure the last underscore:

```
df["val"] = df["path"].str.extract(r'(_\d+)(?!.*_\d+)')
```

Comment: Even though this isn't exactly what I asked for, it works. Accepting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.*` in your pattern so that you only get the last match:

```
>>> df['path'].str.extract(r".*(_\d+)")
    0
0  _1
1  _2
```